# Custom ohai plugin runs but doesn't update attributes

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, ohai-gem

I've written a very simple custom ohai plugin. It should just check if there are any files on the system with .war extensions. The chef client run seems to execute just fine (`re-run ohai and merge results into node attributes`). However, from my knife workstation if I edit all the node attributes, there is nothing coming up for the warFiles mash I set. Don't see the extra attribute in the Chef Manage GUI either. The cookbook is named "inventory". Why isn't my attribute being stored???

My "plugin" really just consists of a ruby file here:

```
 [root@host default]# pwd
 /root/chef/cookbooks/inventory/files/default
 [root@host default]# cat stuff_ohai_will_do.rb
Ohai.plugin(:Packages) do
  provides 'warFiles'

  collect_data(:default) do
    warFiles Mash.new

      so = shell_out('find / -type f -name "*.war"')
      warFiles[:file] = so.stdout.split("\n")
  end
end
```

and

my metadata.rb has these 2 lines in addition to the pre-configured stuff in there:

```
depends 'ohai'
depends 'chef-client'
```

and then a recipe here:

```
 [root@host recipes]# pwd
 /root/chef/cookbooks/inventory/recipes
 [root@host recipes]# cat ohai_plugin.rb
 include_recipe 'ohai::default'
 include_recipe 'chef-client::config'

 ohai "reload" do
   action :reload
 end

 cookbook_file "#{node['ohai']['plugin_path']}/stuff_ohai_will_do.rb" do
   notifies :reload, "ohai[reload]"
 end
```

This is the output of the chef-client run:

```
[root@host chef]# chef-client -o recipe[inventory::ohai_plugin]
Starting Chef Client, version 12.15.19
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["inventory::ohai_plugin"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - inventory (0.1.0)
  - ohai (4.2.2)
  - cron (3.0.0)
  - logrotate (2.1.0)
  - windows (2.0.2)
  - compat_resource (12.16.1)
  - chef-client (7.0.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 12 resources
Recipe: chef-client::config
  * logrotate_app[chef-client] action enable
    * directory[/etc/logrotate.d] action create (up to date)
    * template[/etc/logrotate.d/chef-client] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * directory[/var/run/chef] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/cache/chef] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/lib/chef] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/log/chef] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/etc/chef] action create (up to date)
  * file[/var/log/chef/client.log] action create (up to date)
  * template[/etc/chef/client.rb] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/etc/chef/client.d] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[reload_client_config] action nothing (skipped due to action     :nothing)
Recipe: inventory::ohai_plugin
  * ohai[reload] action reload
    - re-run ohai and merge results into node attributes
  * cookbook_file[/stuff_ohai_will_do.rb] action create (up to date)

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 1/14 resources updated in 04 seconds
```

===== UPDATE =====

I've since found the plugins directory (`/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ohai-8.20.0/lib/ohai/plugins`). Working directly on the chef node, I have put my plugin ruby file directly in this directory. I know it's the right dir as I moved the uptime.rb file out of the dir, re-ran chef-client, and ran ohai | grep -i uptime ... and uptime was gone. Moving the ruby file back to this directory, I was able to restore uptime to ohai's output. I know the below plugin is in the right directory.

***Does ohai just execute everything in this directory or is there some ohai list I need to add the file name to? Otherwise, my code or syntax must be wrong***

```
[root@host plugins]# cat stuff_ohai_will_do.rb
  Ohai.plugin(:Packages) do
    provides 'warFiles'

 collect_data do
   warFiles Mash.new
   so = shell_out('find / -name "*.war"')
   warFiles[:file] = so.stdout
  end
end
```

Comment: Which version of the [_ohai_ cookbook]() are you using? Newer version offer a [`ohai_plugin`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/ohai/#ohai_plugin) resource. Have you updated that recently? Newer versions (IIRC v3) removed the [logic to automatically add the `plugin_path` to the Chef config](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/ohai/blob/v2.1.0/recipes/default.rb#L23-L24).

Comment: ohai 4.2.2 is what was auto-pulled from the supermarket; that's the newest version. When I look at the node I'm testing against, the file gets copied there, but it's going in `/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/inventory/files/default`. I'm not sure if that's the right path for plugins. It's like the contents of that file is never executed. I'm not seeing the "find" command being ran at all. Makes me think it's in the wrong location as ohai isn't seeing it. I don't see any other path in /etc/chef for ohai plugins though.

Comment: As it can be seen in your log output, the file is even put to `/stuff_ohai_will_do.rb`, as `node['ohai']['plugin_path']` is `nil`. It used to go to `/etc/chef/ohai_plugins`, but that IIRC has to be added explicitly to the config now. We didn't have upgraded yet, too, thus I can only suggest to use the new `ohai_plugin` resource or pin `ohai < 3`.

Comment: I reverted to ohai 2.1.0 and that didn't fix the issue. Do you know where I can get documentation on the new ohai_plugin resource? Or any newer example plugins than this (https://github.com/rackerlabs/ohai-plugins/tree/master/plugins == the link from the Chef documentation)? Google doesn't like the underscore and isn't finding relevant docs for "ohai_plugin".

Comment: Here's the repo including the docs: [github.com/chef-cookbooks/ohai](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/ohai#ohai_plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue ... In the Ohai documentation this line describes the `:Name` field:

> Required. (`:Name`) is used to identify the plugin; when two plugins have the same (`:Name`), those plugins are joined together and run as if they were a single plugin. This value must be a valid Ruby class name, starting with a capital letter and containing only alphanumeric characters

I read `valid Ruby class name` not as a comment on the validity of the syntax, but as intending the Ruby class was an existing one (this is my first time attempting Ruby code!). I had taken the "Packages" names from an existing plugin in the directory. Once I changed it to the unique name of "War", it worked.